# AWS ElasticBeanstalk: container keeps restarting

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a multi-container docker Elastic Beanstalk cluster on AWS and my situation is;

- I have 7 docker containers, six of which are Scala applications each
  listening on port 9000 for HTTP traffic.
- The first container is an
  nginx-proxy container that just does a `proxy_pass` to the other
  containers.

What I'm seeing is quite strange and I cannot seem to know where to adjust this in any way – my containers seem to be starting properly, but somehow, their startup keeps getting interrupted by something and all of the containers are told to restart.

Here's what the culprit log looks like;

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/containers/centralapp-core-867cf4f2655c-stdouterr.log
-------------------------------------
Play server process ID is 1
[[37minfo[0m] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://some-mysql-server/somedb-core?characterEncoding=UTF-8
[DEBUG] [09/23/2015 16:30:25.591] [main] [EventStream(akka://application)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [09/23/2015 16:30:25.593] [main] [EventStream(akka://application)] Default Loggers started



-------------------------------------
/var/log/containers/centralapp-push-play-697ba6e223db-stdouterr.log
-------------------------------------
Play server process ID is 1
[[37minfo[0m] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://some-mysql-server/somedb-push?characterEncoding=UTF-8
[[37minfo[0m] application - Push system starting at 2015-09-23T16:39:33.223Z
[INFO] [09/23/2015 16:39:34.582] [main] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [09/23/2015 16:39:35.186] [main] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://application@172.17.0.87:2552]
[INFO] [09/23/2015 16:39:35.196] [main] [Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://application@172.17.0.87:2552]
[[37minfo[0m] play - Starting application default Akka system.
[[37minfo[0m] application - OK: Actor[akka://application/user/PushMaster#-733988473]
[[37minfo[0m] play - Application started (Prod)
[[37minfo[0m] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
[[37minfo[0m] play - Shutdown application default Akka system.
[INFO] [09/23/2015 16:39:39.307] [application-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-14] [akka.tcp://application@172.17.0.87:2552/system/remoting-terminator] Shutting down remote daemon.
[INFO] [09/23/2015 16:39:39.310] [application-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-14] [akka.tcp://application@172.17.0.87:2552/system/remoting-terminator] Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
[INFO] [09/23/2015 16:39:39.367] [ForkJoinPool-3-worker-3] [Remoting] Remoting shut down
[INFO] [09/23/2015 16:39:39.368] [application-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-14] [akka.tcp://application@172.17.0.87:2552/system/remoting-terminator] Remoting shut down.



-------------------------------------
/var/log/containers/centralapp-core-48fc5c7201d9-stdouterr.log
-------------------------------------
Play server process ID is 1
[[37minfo[0m] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://some-mysql-server/somedb-core?characterEncoding=UTF-8
[DEBUG] [09/23/2015 16:30:03.712] [main] [EventStream(akka://application)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [09/23/2015 16:30:03.713] [main] [EventStream(akka://application)] Default Loggers started
```

- this is where the log ends.

It looks like something makes EB think that the deployment has failed, and it attempts to re-deploy everything.

What can be the reason behind this?

Thanks.